# Material Ui checkbox controlled state change not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/rwm5x1w9r4

I have a demo in the above codesandbox. The first checkbox changes all the state to `checked=true` second and third checkboxes just manage their own states. The state changes are working fine but the checkbox visuals are not changing. What do I have to do to make sure the checkboxes behave according to state change?

Comment: the `_id`s are strings 1 and 2 where state names are `checkedB` and `checkedF`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check the console, you will see a warning:

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type
>   checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from
>   uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a
>   controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
>   component.

You are seeing this problem because you are not *controlling* the state of your other two checkboxes from the beginning, but try to manage it yourself later.

```
// but you are not initializing the checkbox ids "1" & "2", so they are uncontrolled.
state = {
  "checkboxA" : true,
  "checkboxB" : true,
  "checkboxC" : true
}
```

What is happening behind the scenes is: the state of your uncontrolled component is maintained by the **dom**, i.e. outside of reacts scope. Later when you ask react to *control* the state, react is unsure of what is the right behaviour and bails out.

You can correct it by explicitly asking react to *control* the other two checkboxes, by setting them in state.

```
state = {
  "checkboxA" : true,
  "1" : true,
  "2" : true
}
```

Here is the link to documentation for [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) components in react official docs.

Update: Here is the sandbox I forked from yours: https://mm3379x0ox.codesandbox.io/

Comment: What if you can't set that in the state until you fetch external data?